# Create New Instance of Derived Class From Parent Class Javascript es6

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

Im getting the following error when doing this.

**Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined**

What I'm trying to do in javascript which I can do in c# is have the child class be able to call the parent class and use functions that instantiate the base class again. Say for instance you have a navbar on a page and each icon takes you to a different page but the navbar is always visible. By inheriting from the parent page I would be able to keep the code dry like we do in c# but for some reason javascript is flipping out when trying to do the same thing even if I just pass null into the super.

Doing this would allow me to have`new Support(browser).someMethod().cb().someMethod()`

---

```
import { Support } from "./community/Support";

export class NavigationController {
   constructor(browser){
       this.browser = browser;
   }
   cb(){
      this.browser.cool()
      return new Support(this.browser);
   }
```

---

```
import { NavigationController } from "../navigation_controller";
export class Support extends NavigationController {
     constructor(browser){
         super(browser);
         this.browser = browser;
     }
     someMethod(){
        this.browser.blah()
        return this;
     }
```

Comment: The perils of circular dependencies… You need to import `Support` first where you're using these modules. Or better yet, remove the dependency.

Comment: Hint: the "super expression" from the error message refers to `extends NavigationController`, not `super(browser)`.

Comment: @Bergi Am i not importing the modules with the first import?

Comment: Yes you are, I mean everywhere you use any of the two modules, you need to import `Support` first.

Comment: @Bergi so I guess maybe there is a better way to do this in JavaScript. In C# it just works simpler in my opinion. Imagine you have a navbar that is visible at all times and when an icon is hit on it it loads a new page under the navbar. What I had done in c# is inherit the class and return a new instance of the class. Yes it’s a circular dependency but it allowed chaining through the entire app based off the workflow which is nice to have. I’m wondering if there is a better way you can think of implementing this as I can only have one circular dependency on a class by the looks of it.